# Change policy with nftables on command line

Tags: firewall, nftables

With iptables I can change the for example INPUT policy with `iptables -P INPUT DROP` to drop. Is there any option to do the same with `nft`?

Editing `/etc/nftables.conf` would work of course but that is not what I want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can redefine an already existing base chain's policy without changing its content. There's no separate keyword for this, it's still `add`:

```
nft add chain family mytable mychain '{ policy drop; }'
```

---

Complete example in a namespace:

`test.nft`:

```
flush ruleset

table ip t {
    chain c {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        oif lo accept
        counter
    }
}
```

setup:

```
# ip netns add test
# ip netns exec test nft -f test.nft
```

alteration:

```
# ip netns exec test nft add 'chain ip t c { policy drop; }'
# ip netns exec test nft list ruleset
table ip t {
    chain c {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy drop;
        oif "lo" accept
        counter packets 0 bytes 0
    }
}
```

The policy was changed, without altering the rules. Using here nft 0.9.5 and kernel 5.7.x . Depending on version behaviour might differ.

There's a [kernel commit from 2015](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=d6b6cb1d3e6f78d55c2d4043d77d0d8def3f3b99) allowing to do only this:

> netfilter: nf_tables: allow to change chain policy without hook if it
> exists
>
> If there's an existing base chain, we have to allow to change the
> default policy without indicating the hook information.
>
> However, if the chain doesn't exists, we have to enforce the presence
> of the hook attribute.
>
> Signed-off-by: Pablo Neira Ayuso pablo@netfilter.org

Before this (around kernel 4.1), one had to provide again the base chain definition (which can't be changed by the way):

```
# ip netns exec test nft add 'chain ip t c { type filter hook output priority 0;  policy drop; }'
```